# Counterspell and Spellbender together: which one is triggered first?

Tags: hearthstone

A quick question regarding the Mage deck: suppose that I'm playing a deck based on Secrets. In a certain turn of the game, I have both **Counterspell** and **Spellbender** activated on my side.

[image]

Is there a rule to determine which one is triggered at first? My though is that the first that you played is the first which is going to be revealed, but I'm not sure about that.

*As a pratical example, suppose that I'm playing against a Paladin, and I predict - due to the state of the game -, that (s)he's gonna buff a minion of his/her with a **Blessing of Kings** (+4/+4 at a minion). Can I foretaste a 5/8 on my side? Or the blessing will "just" vanish?*

Thank you.

Comment: Couldn't both of these be activated? That is: the 1/3 is summoned as the new target, then the spell is countered, leaving the target intact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually counterspell triggers before spellbender in any case.

There is an example
[here](https://youtu.be/6QUM1vicBzk?t=37s) on youtube.

I think it's because in the beginning you cast a spell and *then* you target a minion. This is not an official explanation though.

Answer (score 11):

They will trigger in the order with which they were played. If you played Counterspell first, it will trigger first and counter the spell without triggering Spellbender.

If you played Spellbender first, the spell would target a new minion but then be countered by Counterspell. So you'll end up with a 1/3 minion in your Blessing of Kings case.

Comment: Thank you ChaseC, I didn't think about the possibility of triggering both.

Comment: You're welcome! To clarify, the same thing happens with Hunters sometimes. They will play Misdirection and then Freezing Trap. So Misdirection is triggered and before my minion hits a different target, Freezing Trap is triggered and my minion goes back to my hand :)